# Href link not working in PHP mail

Tags: php, email

I tried to find a solution, but so far, I wasn't able to find anything suitable for my problem.

I want to send a registration mail to every new user I have, this is the PHP for my mail:

```
<?php
$message = '<html>
<body>
<p>Hi ' . $fname . ',</br></br>
welcome!</p>
<p>
<a href="\http://www.home.com/en/verification.php?id=' . $db_id . '&code=' . $code . '\">Please click this link</a> to activate your account.</p>
<p>We hope you enjoy our page and are happy to hear about your experiences!</p>
<p>Your team</p>';

$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "From: Sender <sender@sender.com>";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP ". phpversion();

mail($email, 'Thank you for registering!', $message, $header);
?>
```

Somehow the link is not working correctly in my mails. In Outlook, my Href appears in brackets (e.g. [http://www.home.com/en/verification.php?id=4&code=5]) and in Gmail, only my link description is displayed, but I'm not able to click the link.

Anybody who can help me out?

Comment: you don't need to escape the double quotes inside a single quoted declaration; that's why your href doesn't work. Edit: (see my other comment below) about that `</p>`.

Comment: Ofcoz this woulf not work as this is invalid html markup

Comment: and where is `$email` assigned and other variables?

Comment: Ever think of using a mailing library? I really like http://swiftmailer.org/
I know this doesn't answer your question but you might find it useful

Comment: this is a typo question

Comment: Have u tried to echo $mesage? And see ur output before mailing?

Comment: *"Edit: (see my other comment below) about that </p>"* - scratch that (didn't have time to re-edit); you had that. In any which case; the former part of my original comment is why your code failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is incorrect:

- it is `<br/>` and not `</br>`.
- You do not need to put in html tag
- No need to put \ before and after link

```html
<?php
$message = '<p>Hi ' . $fname . ',<br/><br/>welcome!</p><p><a href="http://www.home.com/en/verification.php?id=' . $db_id . '&code=' . $code . '">Please click this link</a> to activate your account.</p><p>We hope you enjoy our page and are happy to hear about your experiences!</p><p>Your team</p>';  
    
    
    $header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "From: Sender <sender@sender.com>";
    $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP ". phpversion();
    
    mail($email, 'Thank you for registering!', $message, $header);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape is not needed.

```
<a href="http://www.home.com/en/verification.php?id=' . $db_id . '&code=' . $code . '">Please click this link</a> to activate your account.</p>
```